# How many bits of security does a hash as a verifier provide?

Tags: sha256

Let's say I have a binary string `s`, that is generated by a cryptographically secure random byte generator, and a hash function SHA-256.

I am using the hash `h=sha256(s)` as a one-time password verifier and send it to the server, how many bits of security does this provide?

I guess the question is how easy it is to find a preimage of `h`, and the security margin from sha256 seems to be 2^254.9 according to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function_security_summary), am I correct in that assumption?

Does anything change if 256 bits of a 512-bit string are already known? Does this make it easier to find a preimage?

Comment: I'm confused by a number of statements. **(1)** "*I am using the hash h=sha256(s) as a one-time password verifier*". How is that a 1-time password? How is the server using that as a verification? **(2)** "*how easy it is to find a preimage of h*". Where does the hash source (*preimage*) come into play here? Does the server already have *h*? If so why? **General** , I understand the mathematics but I don't understand the intended purpose or use?

Comment: The hash, h, is sent to the server to be stored as a validator. The source, s, is given to another service/person as a one-time authentication key. The key can be validated by the server by hashing it. If it matches any validators then the related permissions are granted. After a validator, like h, is used, h  is removed as validator and it is no longer possible to use that key to get the permissions.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you. One small point, although extremely unlikely, instead of "*If it matches any validators*", the validator should be **paired** with account **ID** just like a password. That will lessen the dependency on the global uniqueness of the validator algorithm. Part and parcel there should probably be a *time out* associated, making a **Triplet** of:  *ID*, *Validator*, *Time*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security of this approach is 2^256, or the entropy of the input, whichever is smaller.  The preimage security of SHA-256 is 2^256 (note that the attack you linked to is on a reduced-round version, so it's not applicable to the full SHA-256).  However, if your input `s` contains less than 256 bits of entropy, then it would be easier to search the input domain, and your scheme would have as much security as the entropy in `s`.  That could be the case if you used a 128-bit `s`, for example.

If `s` is a 512-bit string and 256 bits are known, then the security is still 2^256, since it has 256 unknown bits.